# Add captive run time to phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

I am having certain html files with flash.
which is needed to convert to an android application with captive run time to play flash files without air.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what exactly you're asking. Please elaborate on your question. What exactly do you want to achieve? What have you tried? What was the effect?

Comment: I am having a website with some flash files embedded in it. i want it to convert it into an android application.

I tried it using phonegap but it requires air to play flash on phone, and i want it without air installation , then after my research i found that it can be resolved using captive run time on flash builder.

so is it possible to add captive run time to an eclipse project?